# How to find formula that zero as duplicate but sequentially as 1 and duplicate zero but not sequentially as 0 in a row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates, numbers

[image]

For example, in first row as 1 and third row as 1 but second row as 0 because the second row
the zero duplicate not sequentially

is there any formula to check this in excel?

Comment: Try using `MAX()` & `FREQUENCY()` --> `=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:C3=0,ROW(A1:C3)),IF(A1:C3<>0,ROW(A1:C3))))`

Comment: Check the binary sum, 4 or 1...

Answer (score 2):

So, this works:

[image]

```
IF(OR(BIN2DEC(A1&B1&C1)=4,BIN2DEC(A1&B1&C1)=1),"SEQ","")
```

So convert to binary and test for the results ie 4 or 1. Edit to include for 000 if needed.

Answer (score 2):

May be you could try either of these ones:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D4</kbd>

```
=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:C3=0,ROW(A1:C3)),IF(A1:C3<>0,ROW(A1:C3))))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D5</kbd>

```
=COUNT(SEARCH("00",BYROW(A1:C3,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN("",,x)))))
```

---

If you dont want to get the counts, and want to see the sequence of continuous `0`s then,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=--(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("00",BYROW(A1:C3,LAMBDA(x,CONCAT(x))))))
```

---

Comment: Hi @Mayukh I like the idea of using Frequency, but doesn't it just give the global maximum number of consecutive zeroes e.g. if you had three zeroes in a row, it would give the answer three?

Comment: @TomSharpe Sir, I agree, I was working on that only, but the question itself is not clear. Also OP has not responded yet. When I first asked them to use `MAX()` or `FREQUENCY()`

Comment: Yes the question is ambiguous. I would read it as wanting to check each row separately in which case your formula could easily be adapted to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

I think it finally clicked with me now. Try:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=--IF(B1:B4,,A1:A4+C1:C4<2)
```